# How to move image on touch,Android

Tags: android

i created a iphone app in which, i hv few images.
If i tap on an image for example a boy standing, than it moves from point a to point b.
I used imageview with array of images, and having 6-8 images in different positions, so when user taps, it looks like boy is moving.

The same thing i wanted to implement in ANDROID.

kindly guide me, how can i, move one image from 1 point to another, on touch event.

Suggestions are always appreciated.